# Excel (numbers) formula

Tags: excel, numbers, formula

this should be simple enough, but numbers (on OSX) keeps throwing an error about the ranges being different sizes.

I have a list of numbers, each with an associated date, and I want a sum of all numbers within a particular month (to give, on a separate sheet, a monthly total).

Here is what I've tried:

```
SUMIFS(
    Sheet1::Table 1::D2:D84, 
    MONTH(Sheet1::Table 1::A2:A84), "=04", 
    YEAR(Sheet1::Table 1::A2:A84), "=2014"
)
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I've tried fiddling with it and it just won't accept it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a function inside the range:

```
 =SUMIFS(C1:C25;Month(A1:A25);"=3")
```

than you need to add two (hidden?) columns with Month & year function.
After you build SUMIFS based on the new columns

```
 =SUMIFS(C1:C25;D1:D25;"=4";E1:E25;"=2014")
```

sum all value from C1 to C25 if column of month (D) is equal to 4 and column of year (E) is equal to 2014.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest considering using a SUMIFS function with an upper\lower limit, and then either referencing a cell with the dates, or using their numerical value in the formula (the former is my preference, to reduce hard coded values = easily updated\reused). So something like:

```
=SUMIFS(D2:D84, A2:A84, ">="&E1, A2:A84, "<="&E2)
```

In this example:

- column 'D' has the values you want to sum
- column 'A' has the date values
- columns 'B' and 'C' are treated as irrelevant (for the sake of this formula)
- column 'E' has 2 values, in row 1, the lower limit (for this specific question, the first of April) and in row 2 the upper limit (for this specific question, the final day of April)

Then have your lower limit for dates (the first day from when you would like column 'D' to be counted) in cell E1, and your date upper limit in E2.

Easily updated for future months, so might save you some work down the line.

The next easier option would be to update it to be formatted as a table, because your formula would be slightly more legible, add in some named ranges (in this case, E1 = 'lowerlimit' and E2 = 'upperlimit) to once again make it easier to read the formula, in which case you'd end up with something like:

```
=SUMIFS(table[FigureToBeAccrued], table[dates], ">="&lowerLimit, table[dates], "<="&upperlimit)
```

Might've overcooked this answer, it's my first, so wanted to make sure I didn't skimp. Let me know if you've got any follow up questions.

Comment: That's why you'd set the lowerlimit to the first or april, and the upperlimit to the last day of april, so if it's a date in april, it will be both greater than, or equal to the first day, as well as smaller than, or equal to the final day. This means the 2 conditions will return true for all days of April only, and the sum will work, unless I've misunderstood either the OP or your statement, which is pretty likely, this is a new medium for me.

Comment: That closing parenthesis, too used to double tapping 'enter'. I'm not sure I've understood correctly what you mean by indenting rows, but I've added a small edit in to hopefully clarify. Pics would be so helpful right now, but insufficient rep.